# Dynamic Web Project with Maven is deploying webapp resources into class folder

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I'm not sure why Maven (Eclipse?) is so finnicky but I am wasting hours trying to get my static resources (javascript and css file) to deploy as part of my web application. These are the steps I used:

In Eclipse I started by creating a new Dynamic Web Project. Then I went to "Configure" and selected "convert to Maven project".

my directory structure is there with the following:

```
src
|
---main
   |
   ---java
      |
      ---*.java files
   ---webapp
      |
      ---styles.css
```

The problem is with that styles.css class. I expect it to go into my WEB-INF directory but it ain't. Deploying the project to a server results in 404 for all resource calls. I exported the project to a war file and exploded it and found that styles.css was moved to the WEB-INF/classes directory. Classes! I'm not sure why since the file is in the webapp directory in my Eclipse project.

I setup my POM as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyProj</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>My Project</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <project.basedir>c:/MyProj</project.basedir>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, what it under `webapp` should go to the root of the war. But it would be *strange* to put a css file under `WEB-INF`, because it could not be served by container ...

Nevertheless, with that structure it should **never** end under `WEB-INF/classes` unless you said somewhere to maven that `webapp` was in fact a *resource* directory ...

Try to clean and rebuild from Eclipse, and if it does not work, build directly with `mvn` command line to determine if the problem is in the `pom.xml` file or in Eclipse config

Comment: Strange indeed. I'm away from the computer right now but I will try this when I get home. You can see some constructs in the pom that I pasted indicating specific things for war deployment and I wonder if these are the issue. I build and deploy by right clicking on the project and selecting Run - > Server, and I assume this process uses maven but I'm not ot sure.